# Is there a way to save click event on toggle state with local/session storage using jquery

Tags: jquery, local-storage

I have an icon to toggle a popup div but I want the div to remain hidden if a user closed it on a page then that hidden state should apply even if the user navigates to a different page. How can I achieve this using local/session storage?

```
<section class="floating-cta"> 
  <div class="qq-float-cta">
    <a href="#" class="cta-callnow">
        <div class="cta-top"><h3>Call now on 012 345 6789</h3></div>
        <p>For an accurate, immediate response </p>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="cta-getquote">
        <div class="cta-bottom"><h3>Get your quote</h3></div>
        <p>Guaranteed response in 10 minutes within business hours.</p>
    </a>
  </div>
</section>
<i class="fa fa-times-circle-o"></i>

<script>
        $('.fa-times-circle-o').click(function(){
            $('.floating-cta').fadeToggle("slow");
            $("i",this).toggleClass("fa fa-times-circle-o fa fa-commenting")
    });
</script>
```

I expect that when a user closes the section it should remain closed when he/she goes to a different page and open it again if he/she wants to display it by clicking the icon again.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `cookies` instead.

Something like this:

```
<script>
        function setCookie(key, value) {
            var expires = new Date();
            expires.setTime(expires.getTime() + (1 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
            document.cookie = key + '=' + value + ';expires=' + expires.toUTCString();
        }    
        function getCookie(key) {
            var keyValue = document.cookie.match('(^|;) ?' + key + '=([^;]*)(;|$)');
            return keyValue ? keyValue[2] : null;
        }
        $('.fa-times-circle-o').click(function(){
            $('.floating-cta').fadeToggle("slow");
            $("i",this).toggleClass("fa fa-times-circle-o fa fa-commenting");
            setCookie('hide_popup', '1');
        });
        if(getCookie('hide_popup') == '1'){
            $('.floating-cta').hide();
        }
</script>
```